# sending mails from php application

Tags: php, email, bulk

On daily basis I am sending bulk mails to my customers from my php application. Right now I am using the PHP built-in mail() function inside a loop construct. When I checked my mail server log for the total mails sent, I could see some deviation. When I checked about php mail() on the net, people are saying that we should not use mail() for sending bulk mailers (even php.net has mentioned about this)

Now my question is which mailer function I have to use for sending bulk mailers - Mail::Pear package, PHPMailer class, swift mailer or the other...

Please suggest me

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending bulk e-mails out yourself, you will need to keep a VERY close eye on what are known as DNSRBLs.  The PHP mail() function is sort of a rudimentary way of sending e-mail.  The most basic forms of usage are easy to detect and get caught by spam traps on a very regular basis.  You can use a tool such as the various mail sending classes you mentioned (I personally like [Ultimate E-mail Toolkit](https://github.com/cubiclesoft/ultimate-email), which I wrote and maintain) to help cover over some of the difficulty in sending correctly formed e-mail and avoid a lot of filtering issues.  You should also read:

https://blog.codinghorror.com/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code/

A correct PTR record and SPF are quite important.  DKIM is less important and slightly more annoying to set up.  The hard part of all three is getting them configured just right so that the majority of systems let e-mail through.  It is my opinion that you should not pull your hair out if someone doesn't receive your e-mail.  *Their* e-mail provider is broken and they should set up their own private e-mail server instead of using the big public guys (GMail, Yahoo, Hotmail/Live/Outlook.com, their ISP, etc).

Also, don't send bulk e-mail from your main website server.  If that server gets stuck on a blacklist, it becomes very hard to send normal e-mails.